# How do I install Clang 4.0 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, apt-get, clang

I need to install Clang 4.0 and Clang++ 4.0 on my Ubuntu 14.04 box.  The most recent version I can find in the apt-get package list is 3.5.  How do I install 4.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can do it this way:

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-4.0 main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clang-4.0 lldb-4.0
```

This is based on [the answer provided here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257699/30848) updated to reflect [the repositories found here](https://apt.llvm.org).

Comment: To install latest stable in 2020 - `sudo bash -c "$(wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh)"`

Comment: @brokenfoot This is decent info. But since this answer is 3+ years old, might be best if you expand your comment to an answer. Please be sure to include the version of Ubuntu in your answer when you post it.